# How can I round the edges of a css border-bottom

Tags: html, css, sass

I am wanting to add rounded edges to a border-bottom css property, but struggling to get what I need.

I need this to look at the picture below, tried various methods but looking to find one that suits this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this is possible without using the `pseudo selecter` `::before`.

Hope this helps :)

```css
h1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
```